# Call method from Firebase event to take a photo

Tags: android, events, firebase

I am working on a project where I need an Andorid phone to take a picture and send it via FTP whenever a `ESP8266` does an HTTP request.

At this point, I already coded the entire app, but the crucial part of it isn't working, which is the workaround I found to receive a "request" from the wifi module - I implemented the Firebase API in my project to listen to changes on a database table.

The ESP is sending a GET to my Apache server, which runs a PHP file that changes the database value, triggering the event on Android that would call the method to take the photo and send it.

There is a problem: If I call the method to take the photo through a button, it works perfectly, but if I call the same method inside the Firebase Event handler it just crashes the app.

Just to make it clear, I know my code will probably make anyone anything more than my near zero experience with Android cry with so many mistakes. But this is just a workaround for a financial problem that could resolve my need by this app just by purchasing an IP camera. Anyway, I would appreciate any help.

The code:

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.btn_tirarFoto:

            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    takePicture();
                }
            }.start();

        break;

    }
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    boolInicial = true; //This prevents the event to run on activity launch

    ipRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(!boolInicial) {

                new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        takePicture();
                    }
                }.start();

            }else{
                boolInicial = false;
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}

public void takePicture() {
    cam = Camera.open();
    if (cam != null) {
        try {
            cam.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
            cam.stopPreview();
            cam.startPreview();
            cam.takePicture(null, null,new Camera.PictureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                    foto = data;
                    BitmapFactory.Options bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bfo.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), null, bfo);

                    iv_foto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    thread.start();

                    camera.stopPreview();
                    camera.release();
                    camera = null;

                    ipRef.setValue("b");
                    boolInicial = true;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Can't take picture!" + ex.toString());
        }
    }
}

Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        ByteArrayInputStream bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(foto);

        try {
            FTPClient mFtpClient = new FTPClient();
            mFtpClient.setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000);
            mFtpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName("IP"));
            mFtpClient.login("user", "passw");
            mFtpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("ftp");
            mFtpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            mFtpClient.storeFile("ftp.png", bs);
            mFtpClient.logout();
            mFtpClient.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
});
```

I managed to get this working, the code now looks like this:

```
public void takePicture() {
    cam = Camera.open();
    if (cam != null) {
        try {
            cam.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
            cam.stopPreview();
            cam.startPreview();
            cam.takePicture(null, null,new Camera.PictureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                    foto = data;
                    BitmapFactory.Options bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bfo.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), null, bfo);

                    iv_foto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    new Thread() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                        ByteArrayInputStream bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(foto);

                        try {
                            FTPClient mFtpClient = new FTPClient();
                            mFtpClient.setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000);
                            mFtpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.107"));
                            mFtpClient.login("vrech", "gabrieli");
                            mFtpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("ftp");
                            mFtpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                            mFtpClient.storeFile("ftp.png", bs);
                            mFtpClient.logout();
                            mFtpClient.disconnect();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        }
                    }.start();

                    camera.stopPreview();
                    camera.release();
                    camera = null;

                    ipRef.setValue("b");
                    boolInicial = true;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Can't take picture!" + ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the crash?  Can you post the `logcat` or stack trace that is produced?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention this. It says that it Failed to connect to camera service and points to the line that Camera.open(); is.

Comment: On possible problem is that you are adding a listener every time `onResume()` runs and the [listener is never removed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#detach_listeners). If your activity is paused and resumed a number of times, you will get multiple `onDataChange()` callbacks, resulting in multiple threads trying to take a picture.

Comment: @RafaelVrech Since your issue seems to be an FOSS (free and open source) kind of deal, why not take an already done product such as ["PAW"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.fun2code.android.pawserver&hl=en), that has its own HTTPd / Android interface, and just use what is ready? I have been using it, for other purposes, but camera / file transfer are part of it... Em todo caso, teu problema parece ser de `Context` um Objecto Dalvik que serve para indicar ao OS, qual "usuário" (e aplicativos são usuários no Android), que está requisitando acesso ao Hardware.

Comment: Finally, read this [solving the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), about your approach. It seems you are doing a lot of unnecessary work, in a problem that isnt your own.

Comment: @Bonatti and qbix, thank you for your answers. I was really researching your sugestions in the last 2 hours, found that PAW is really useful but it is not for my project, once I need the picture to be taken programatically (without preview), and thanks again for that XY problem idea, It was very helpul. 
I ended up finding that the problem was on the threads: I just removed that last thread and put it inside the takePicture method. And it just worked!
I will edit the main post to what I managed to make it work.

Comment: @RafaelVrech Just to say, when you make a `GET` request, you can use BeanShell, or event direct Android classes. I have done, but couldnt find easily a "Joke" program I did, that used TTS (Text-toSpeech) to make garble noises for an Halloween head costume, to post as an answer. It was pretty easy, Something like a single XHTML page, with a couple of tags. (likewise, calling another already built function to take a screenshot, and post it over the Internet/LAN is even an [example shown here](http://paw-android.fun2code.de/pdf/paw_functions.pdf)). Anyway, welcome to the forum, and good luck.